# Probability Distribution on $\mathbb{R}^2$

Tags: probability-theory

Question here from Klenke's Probability Theory. Let $F:\mathbb{R}^2\rightarrow [0,1]$. Show that $F$ is the distribution of a unique probability measure $\mu$ on $(\mathbb{R}^2,\mathcal{B}(\mathbb{R}^2))$ if and only if $F$ is monotone increasing and right continuous and then it gives some inequality and limit conditions as well.

What does it mean by monotone increasing? This doesn't seem to make sense if the domain is $\mathbb{R}^2$. Is it possible this is a typo? Also what does the author mean by distribution in this context? In this chapter the book defines what a random variable and then gives the definition of the distribution of a random variable. For this question is the idea that I will construct a random variable and a corresponding probability measure?

Comment: Monotone increasing simply means $F(x+s,y+s)\ge F(x,y)$ for all non-negative $s$ and $t$ and all $x$ and $y$.  $F$ will be the cumulative distribution function for the jointly distributed $(X,Y)$ where $F(x,y)=\mathbb P(X\le x, Y \le y)$

Comment: @Henry  Minor typo.  You meant to write $F(x+s, y+t)$.

Comment: @lulu - indeed I did, so should have said $F(x+s,y+t)\ge F(x,y)$ ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In this context, $F$ monotone increasing means that for any two vectors $(x,y)$ and $(u,v)$ that satisfy $x \le u$ and $y \le v$, we have
$$F(x,y) \le F(u,v)\,.$$